# Method once does not exist

Tags: php, jwt, lumen

Problem with some method "once", is it ORM problem? I don't know...

[image]
AuthController :

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $validateData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email'    => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ], ApiValidator::getMessages());

    if($validateData->fails()){
        $errors = $validateData->messages();
        return response()->json(ApiValidator::response(array(), $errors), 400);
    }
    try {

        if (!$token = $this->jwt->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json(ApiValidator::response(array(), array('Bad credentials')), 401);
        }

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(ApiValidator::response(array(), array('Token expired')), 401);

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(ApiValidator::response(array(), array('Token invalid')), 401);

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(ApiValidator::response(array(), array('Token absent' => $e->getMessage())), 401);

    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

I use lumen 5.5 tymondesign/jwt-auth

Comment: It might be in the JTWAuth package that you are using.  Look into the attempt method for JWTAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've defined the authentication guards for the app by creating an `auth.php` file in the `config` directory of your app. Here's what mine looks like:

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => \App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```